# How to display the result of this checkbox checked function to a text feild

Tags: jquery

```
 Please let me know how to display the result to a text box instead of span class
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rynslmns/6NJ8e/10/

Comment: Please be more specific, and don't just link to JSFiddle; provide the relevent code with an explanation of what's going wrong, and what you'd like to happer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change those spans to text inputs, your code should look like this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
total  = document.getElementById('payment-total');
total1 = document.getElementById('payment-rebill');

for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
        total.value = parseFloat(total.value) + add;
        total1.value = parseFloat(total1.value) + add;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6NJ8e/98/